# What size of SD card can an HTC Desire accomodate?

Tags: external-sd

I have replaced my 2gb sd card with a 16gb one so i can store more music. Now I can't get the phone to play any music at all it says to make more space before opening app'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

It should be able to take up to 32 GB SDHC cards like almost all other devices.  Did you format the card?  `Settings -> SD card and phone storage -> Unmount SD card` and then `Format SD card` or similar, make sure to backup anything on it first if needed.

Comment: I can confirm that 16GB and 32 GB cards work without problems on stock Desire

Answer (score 0):

As per the phone [specification](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire-3077.php)

> microSD, up to 32GB, 4GB included,

Answer (score 0):

It's INFURIATING that HTC fails to mention this in the pdf manual.  I've been looking and all that's mentioned about it is how to put the card in.

I found one review that claims up to 164 GB but I wouldn't swear to that. One other review says the spec is 128 GB and that he tested a 64 GB card that worked flawlessly.

I'm sure I saw something in out other paperwork that came wit the phone that said 32 GB but not sure about that.

I was looking because my wife wants added storage for hers. I'm going with 32 GB. My own failed a few months ago and I'll probably never own another HTC product because of that. The SIM card popped out for no reason and the mechanism was junk, others have mentioned that and it seems a really stupid way to make it, (SD card is retained the same way) one guy said both failed on his within a few days or each other... again, dumb design and I'll never own another HTC because of that.

But most phones seem to specify up to 32 GB. IMO all phones should be able to use what ever size card you can get no matter how large and you might find out a larger one will work. Perhaps they're concerned about seek time or something but who knows. But it's storage, not operating memory.

Thing is when I got a 32 GB card for my phone I'm using now you could get a 2-pack having 2 16 GB cards for 10-15 bucks but a single 32 GB card was 20 bucks. So a larger card might not be worth it.  Gigs is a lot of storage for a phone. You might need that much if you're running a bunch of apps that need storage but if it's just pics and such you probably want to back those up on PC or cloud storage anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"The HTC Desire 510 comes with 4 GB of internal storage, but has an expansion card slot that supports microSD memory cards with up to 128 GB of additional storage." Direct quote from HTC website